# docker-compose oci runtime error executable file not found (in linked container)

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup docker & compose for running integration tests

I have the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    tests:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.tests
        links:
            - web
            - maindb
    web:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.web
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - .:/code
            - logvolume01:/var/log
        links:
            - maindb
    maindb:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example

volumes:
    logvolume01: {}
```

**web** container itself works pretty fine

```
$ docker-compose  -p wh  run web
Starting wh_maindb_1 ... done
2017/07/27 22:05:34 [I] http server Running on http://:8080
```

But when I run **tests** container, I get the error

```
$ docker-compose  -p wh  run tests
Starting wh_maindb_1 ... done
Starting 6faff07f7671_6faff07f7671_wh_web_1 ... 
Starting 6faff07f7671_6faff07f7671_wh_web_1 ... error

ERROR: for 6faff07f7671_6faff07f7671_wh_web_1  Cannot start service web: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"web\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

Here is my Dockerfile.web

```
$ cat Dockerfile.web 
FROM ubuntu:xenial
WORKDIR /app
ADD bin/* /app/
CMD ["/app/web"]
```

/app/web is dynamically linked daemon written in Golang 1.6

And some version info

```
$ docker version 
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:23:31 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:19:04 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false

$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.14.0, build c7bdf9e
docker-py version: 2.4.2
CPython version: 2.7.12
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Comment: What does this output? `docker-compose  -p wh  run web ls -l`

Comment: @Robert,

`$ docker-compose -p wh run web ls -l`

`Starting wh_maindb_1 ... done`

`total 21272`

`-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  2288256 Jul 24 21:19 scheduler`

`-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  5855104 Jul 24 21:19 sender`

`-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 13631752 Jul 24 21:19 web`

Comment: Sorry. I should asked for tests: `docker-compose -p wh run tests ls -l`. And please show its Dockerfile

Comment: @Robert


https://gist.github.com/mialinx/ad403ad702203b6602ba7c8d9af9419f  - `docker-compose -p wh run tests ls -l`

https://gist.github.com/mialinx/60d573c60224a14250fd0fd802e8fefe - 
Dockerfile.tests

Comment: Can you please run as this to discard any cache or already built container? `docker-compose  -p wh up --force-recreate --build tests`

Comment: @Robert
I have removed all images with 
`docker images | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi -f`

than I have ran your command and here are the results
https://gist.github.com/mialinx/6d761f778721cc92015ebe73c3f2cd7c

Comment: If you don't care, try again but removing containers first: `docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)`

Comment: Also, I think that this is a docker-compose bug. You can try updating it, maybe.

Comment: Cleaning old containers with `docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)`  solved the problem. Now tests run fine.  Magic!  Could you add an answer ? I'll mark the question as solved.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is maybe related to some docker-compose bug.

Try cleaning containers

```
docker-compose down
```

Alternatively this (you will lose your container data):

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```